# Consuming from kafka using kafka methods and spark streaming gives different result

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to consume some data from Kafka using spark streaming.

I have created 2 jobs,

1. A simple kafka job that uses:

```
consumeFirstStringMessageFrom(topic)
```

that gives topic expected values.

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "SA_LIST",
    "login": "username@mycompany.com",
    "updateDate": "2020-09-09T14:58:39.775Z",
    "content": [
      {
        "sku": "800633955",
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ],
    "saCode": "E40056",
    "clientId": "30179801688090",
    "$setOnInsert": {
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  "operation": "UPDATE",
  "type": "List"
}
```

2. A spark streaming job:

```scala
val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaConfig.broker)
      .option("subscribe", kafkaConfig.topic)
      .option("startingOffsets", kafkaConfig.startingOffsets)
      .load()

 df.writeStream
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", false)
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 seconds"))
      .start().awaitTermination()
```

It shows the following result

```sh
{
  "key": "I4NTY4NV9MSVNUX1dJU0hMSVNUIg==",
  "value": "eyJkYXRhIjp7InR5cGUiOiJXSVNITElTVCIsImxvZ2luIjoiZHJlYW1lcjJAeW9wbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ1cGRhdGVEYXRZSI6Ikxpc3QifQ==",
  "topic": "PLP_GLOBAL_QA",
  "partition": 0,
  "offset": 1826,
  "timestamp": "2020-09-10T16:09:08.606Z",
  "timestampType": 0
}
```

It seems that it shows topic info (key, value, topic, partition, offset,...) Am I missing something?

I can add more info if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spark Streaming jobs shows you the data in a serialized form whereas your Kafka Consumer already de-serialized it.

According to the [Spark Structured Kafka integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) you are getting not only key and value of the Kafka message, but also other (meta) information. Here is the schema for each message you are getting from Kafka:

```sh
Column      Type
key         binary
value       binary
topic       string
partition   int
offset      long
timestamp   timestamp
timestampType   int
```

If you only want to select the key and value or even only the value you can select them and cast them to a human readable string:

```
[...]
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```